# ttk.Labelframe color issue

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am coding a bit of a GUI using tkinter in Python, using ttk items such as the notebook, treeview, and labelframes (and a lot of other things too) everything I was doing looked great, until I changed the color from the "system color" of beige, to white.

Here's an (updated!) iteration of the code (minimum reproducible example, showing just the problem, and not much else!):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font

window = Tk()

s=ttk.Style()

window.title("test window")
window.geometry("405x505+0+0")
section_1 = Frame(window, width = 405, height = 505)
section_1.place(x=0, y=0)

tabControl_1 = ttk.Notebook(section_1, height = 470, width = 395) #395
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl_1, style='new.TFrame')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl_1)

tabControl_1.add(tab1, text='Devices')
tabControl_1.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tabControl_1.place(y=5,x=5)

label = ttk.Label(text="Detected devices will appear here", style="my.TLabel")

lf = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, labelwidget=label, labelanchor='nw')
lf.pack()
lf.place(x=20,y=20)

treeview_frame = Frame(lf, width = 301, height = 201, background="white")
treeview_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
treeview_frame.grid_propagate(False)

s.configure('my.TLabel', background='white', font=('Segoe UI', 9))
s.configure('new.TFrame', background ='white')
window.resizable(False,False)
window.mainloop()
```

Here's an (updated) screenshot of what that looks like, visually:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6r3O.jpg

Essentially, my question is, what is the simplest and/or best way to get all of those patchy bits around the labelframe to be white?

If someone could explain what I'm missing here, logic wise, I would much appreciate it.

**UPDATE:**

Whilst we were kinda "getting there" slowly in the comments, it seems that Derek has gotten the simple non-destructive solution for this, with his answer.

The lesson here is that if your labelframe references a label, you can change styling for both the label and the labelframe, and this has an effect on the output.

Working from Derek's answer, I was able to get this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK96e.jpg

..Which is perfect, essentially.

Every time I come onto here I get made to feel like I am really stupid (entirely though my own fault, of course), thanks for the help to those that chipped in.

Comment: Have you tried `self.tk_setPalette("white")`? This will affect all `tk` objects.

Comment: Hello @Derek, thanks for your comment - before investigating your suggestion, I wanted to implement something that would remove a source of error. Essentially, I made a frame to populate the labelframe, and the treeview item can eventually go inside this frame, and if the frame is larger than the treeview, I can use "place" to recreate the padding I previously had. Please check out my updated code and screenshot - the color patchiness issue seems to be entirely related to the labelframe. I will now look into "setPalette" and get back to you.

Comment: Hi again @Derek, I have tried "self.tk_setPalette("white")", replacing "self" with "window", "tab1", and "lf", all this seems to do is change the color of my background (the main background, atop which everything sits), and seems to have no other impact. I have even tried putting "background="white"" inside the setPalette item, it only ever effects the bottom layer of my window, (which by the way, I want to keep as grey!). If you have any other suggestions, I am all ears. Thanks

Comment: Try: `s=ttk.Style();s.configure('.', background='white')`.

Comment: Hello @8349697, I have tried your bit of code, and it was partially successful, it made the color around the labelframe white (yay!) but it also made an area next to the ttk notebook tabs white, an unintended side effect. Here is what that looks like: (https://imgur.com/a/HGwfYZ3). Is it possible to make this into a seperate style used only by the labelframe, so that it doesn't affect other widgets, or something along those lines? I have experimented (and checked some documentation) but it's not too clear to me.

Comment: A dot ('.') is the root style. To change the appearance of each ttk widget, you can configure this style. If you mix [tkinter and ttk widgets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-widgets) with the same name, side effects are inevitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change background color of `ttk.Labelframe` like this.

```py
s=ttk.Style()

s.theme_use("default")
s.configure("TLabelframe", background = "white")
```

Comment: Wait, what... am I stupid? This seems rather straight forward, I could have sworn I tried something similar to this at some point, then taking it back out because "it wasn't working" or something. Here I was, ready to chalk this up as another tkinter annoyance, but actually it's suprisingly simple. I had set the TLabel styling to white (which got me halfway there), so I guess I also just needed to get the TLabelframe styling, as well. What's better is that I ensured not to configure default TLabelframe, but created a custom one.. AND it let me do all this with theme "vista", will update post!

Comment: Yeah, it works with all themes (just tried it).